# Is it true there exists $f:S^{2n}\longrightarrow S^{2n}$ making the diagram commutative?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $g:\mathbb R\mathbb P^{2n}\longrightarrow \mathbb R\mathbb P^{2n}$ be a continuous map where $\mathbb R\mathbb P^{2n}=\mathbb S^{2n}/\{\pm x\}$. Is it true there exists $f:\mathbb S^{2n}\longrightarrow \mathbb S^{2n}$, possibly continuous, such that the diagram $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
S^{2n} @>{f}>> S^{2n}\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathbb R\mathbb P^{2n} @>{g}>> \mathbb R\mathbb P^{2n}
\end{CD}$$
is commutative? In the vertical arrow are the natural projections $q:S^{2n}\longrightarrow \mathbb R\mathbb P^{2n}$.

Maybe the even dimension is not needed.

**Important Consequence:** Once this problem has been solved we can conclude every continuous map $f:\mathbb R\mathbb P^{2n}\longrightarrow \mathbb R\mathbb P^{2n}$ has a fixed point. This is done as follows:

Using degree theory, or only homotopy theoric arguments, we are able to show that for every continuous map $f:\mathbb S^{2n}\longrightarrow \mathbb S^{2n}$ there exists $x_0\in\mathbb S^{2n}$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$ or $f(x_0)=-f(x_0)$. Consequently, if there exists the function $f$ that solves my problem then taking such $x_0$ gives $g([x_0])=[x_0]$, that is, $[x_0]$ is a fixed point of $g$.

Comment: How about the identity?

Comment: It doesn't work for in this case $g([x])=[x]$..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such a continuous map $f$ follows from the lifting property of the universal cover.

Comment: I don't know this result, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Do you know about universal covers and fundamental groups?

Comment: Well, let us say I don't, but this problem arose when I was trying to solve an algebraic topology problem which was in a chapter after fundamental groups and covering spaces, so I'll have to study it..

Comment: Yes, definitely learn about them.  Discussion of the lifting property I am citing starts on page 60 of Hatcher which is available for free online.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it. I added a nice consequence of this problem.